# mod_rewrite: optional GET variables in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have this .htaccess script that takes a URL with GET variables that would typically look like:

domain.com/index.php?PID=test&ID=test2

and allow a URL such as this to be used to hide the names of the GET variables

domain.com/test/test2/

This is the .htaccess script-

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?PID=$1&ID=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?PID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works as it should, allowing either 1 or 2 variables to be passed, but I need an instance where *No* variables are passed, for example a straight up domain call (e.g. domain.com), but the above rule is throwing additional trailing slashes after the domain without a variable (e.g. domain.com//) and causing a redirect loop.. By default, I'm trying to forward users to domain.com/home/ (this is handled in the PHP script itself)

```
if(!isset($_GET['PID']))
    {
     header("Location:home");
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Trying to understand .htaccess and mod_rewrite is a bit of a pain in the neck...

Answer (score 0):

The redirect happens because of the first rule you have set. Add the condition to exclude the URLs which only request the server root:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```